# Imperative JS to Reactive JS - "if statement" sparkAR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spark-ar-studio

I need some help regarding Reactive JS and  "if statement"
 I do not know how to implement a simple code in Reactive JS
something like thisin Spark AR:

```
if( boolvalue=true)
 {
 vidTex.url = "https://yourvideo";
 }
 else 
 {
  vidTex.url = "";
 }
```

I found a piece of code done in for Spark Reactive JS like this:

```
   vidTex.url = Reactive.val(""); // Stop
   vidTex.url = Reactive.val("https://yourvideo"); // Play
```

But I do not know how to implement the if bool true?

Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ternary conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) for that:

```
vidTex.url = Reactive.val(boolvalue ? "https://yourvideo" : "")
```